# Why i cant see my h:commandLink?

Tags: jsf

I m developing JSF and primefaces, i have a `<h:commandLink>` for my methods but, the commandLink does not show, it just show when i put the mouse on it.

Why?

```
<h:commandLink action="#{Bean.method()}" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-save"/> Guardar
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: what is in your css

Comment: @A. Castro As far I understand, you're trying to display a button with 'Guardar' text and save icon next to it, right? Why don't you do it with Primefaces? It's much easier...